# Scrapy SQLite3 error?

Tags: sqlite, scrapy

I wrote a spider and need to store items in a SQLite3 database, but every time I get an error. Please help me, since I'm stuck now! This is the spider code:

```
response_fld=response.url
text_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'text' )]/@id ").extract() 
pass_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'password')]/@id").extract()     
file_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'file')]/@id").extract()
```

Output in JSON format:

```
{"pass_input": ["tbPassword"], "file_input": [], "response_fld": "http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com/Signup.aspx", "text_input": ["tbUsername"]}
{"pass_input": [], "file_input": [], "response_fld": "http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com/default.aspx", "text_input": []}
{"pass_input": ["tbPassword"], "file_input": [], "response_fld": "http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com/login.aspx", "text_input": ["tbUsername"]}
{"pass_input": [], "file_input": [], "response_fld": "http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com/Comments.aspx?id=0", "text_input": []}
```

Pipeline code:

```
import sqlite3
from os import path

class SQLiteStorePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('./project.db')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, domain, item):
        self.cur.execute("insert into links (link) values(item['response_fld'][0]") 
        self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(item['text_input'][0];")
        self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(item['pass_input'][0];")
        self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(item['file_input'][0];")
        self.conn.commit()
        return item

    def handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

Error:

```
File "/home/abdallah/isa/isa/pipelines.py", line 22, in process_item
    self.cur.execute("insert into links (link) values(item['response_fld'][0]")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "['response_fld']": syntax error
```

Database scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE "Targets" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "domain" TEXT);

CREATE TABLE "Links" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "link" TEXT, "target" INT, FOREIGN KEY (target) REFERENCES Targets(id));

CREATE TABLE "Input_Types" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "type" TEXT);

CREATE TABLE "Inputs" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "input_name" TEXT, "link_id" INT, "input_type" INT, FOREIGN KEY (input_type) REFERENCES Input_Types(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your invalid SQL query:

```
self.cur.execute("insert into links (link) values(item['response_fld'][0]")
```

According to the the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html), you should do:

```
self.cur.execute("insert into links (link) values(?)", (item['response_fld'][0], ))
```

Comment: self.cur.execute("insert into links (link) values(?)", (item['response_fld'][0], ))
 exceptions.TypeError: 'MySpider' object has no attribute         '__getitem__'

Comment: @right.sowrd, that's a different problem. Your `process_item` signature is wrong. according to the docs it should be `def process_item(self, item, spider)` and not `def process_item(self, domain, item)`

Comment: thanks a lot ,it works for some , but still have errors    ` first : only "h" is what stored in DB, ` and when trying to store other items i got  `exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @right.sowrd This is also a different problem. `pass_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'password')]/@id").extract()` returns always a list. but i some cases (looking at json output in your question) it is empty. You should do `pass_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'password')]/@id").extract()[0]` - to put into an item field not a list which could be empty but the actual password. this is more logical and will not confuse the pipeline. Why `pass_input` sometimes is empty? You should see the scraped page and debug your path query.

Comment: xpath some times returns an empty list , since not all pages have an `input form`

Comment: i have tried your solution but , i got >> 
`line 25, in parse_item
     item['text_input']=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'text' )]/@id ").extract()[0]
 exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range
`

Comment: please help  needed 
up up ??

Comment: If a page doesn't have needed form and `hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'password')]/@id").extract()` gets an empty list, and you still want to create an item the password just being empty, simply do something like: `query_result = hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'password')]/@id").extract(); pass_input = query_result[0] if query_result else some_default_value_for_password_field`

Comment: thanks for this good hint , but if only want to    extract input fields with values  , exclude empty one  >> should i change ` xpath or item pipeline`